# Adding external cpp files to Android Studio JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an Android project setup in Android Studio.
I'm using NDK and JNI so I have some cpp/h files in the jni folder. I can use them and everything is fine.
I also have another folder somewhere in my harddrive (which is not under the Android project root folder) with more cpp files.
So in Android.mk I added the path to both local (jni folder) files and the external files directory path. Everything compiles and everything works fine.
The issue I'm having is how to actually link to those cpp files in the external folder so I can actually edit them inside Android Studio or at least see the functions and member names. Currently I edit those files in notepad++ save and then go back to Android Studio to call the methods etc.

The external folder is simply a folder with some cpp files inside. It's not a module, it does not have a build.gradle or anything like that.

Is what I'm asking even possbile? 
I hope the question was clear enough. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: maybe creating links to folders/files ?

Comment: Could you please show an example how to create such links?

Comment: on windows you can use something like `mklink /H helium ..\home\concisecomp\helium` - it creates hard link. 
on linux you can try `ln ..\home\concisecomp\helium helium`

Comment: Ohh excellent! Will this survive svn repository commits?

Comment: didn't try it yet with svn, but probably it will add whole file instead of just reference. to just store reference you would need to make symbolic links but it will probably not work with building on windows